# $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,X_{n-1})$ for ${n \ge 1}$. Show $\{2^nX_n,n\ge0\}$ converges a.s. to $0$

Tags: probability-theory

Define $\{X_n\}$ inductively as follows: $X_0=1$ and $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,X_{n-1})$ for ${n \ge 1}$. Show $\{2^nX_n,n\ge0\}$ converges a.s. to $0$.

I tried to use the something like strong law of large number, actually that's the only method I have learned to prove a.s. convergence. But the problem lies in that $X_n$ is dependent...

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left[ {{2^n}{X_n}} \right] = \frac{{0 + 2\mathbb{E}\left[ {{2^{n - 1}}{X_{n - 1}}} \right]}}{2} = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{2^{n - 1}}{X_{n - 1}}} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {2{X_1}} \right] = 2\mathbb{E}\left[ {{X_1}} \right] = 1$ so showing that could prove difficult, considering it isn't true.

Comment: @Alen, there is possibility that $\{2^nX_n\}$ converges a.s. to 0 but does not converge in $L_1$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606329/how-pi-i-0n-xi-i-converges-a-s-to-0-provided-xi-n0-iid-and-e-xi

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot about that

Comment: Hint: First, it helps to think in terms of uniform (0,1) variables $U_i$. So, for example, $X_1 = U_1$, and $X_2 = X_1 U_2$. Continue in this manner. Then think about $\log (2^n X_n)$. It's actually a sum of i.i.d. variables and SLLN applies. Apply SSLN and what conclusion do you draw?

Comment: @Will Nelson, thank you so much!Ahahah, I'm really depressing. I thought for a long time but why I cannot find out these seemingly simple facts!!!